# Signed vs Unsigned Binary numbers interpertaion

Tags: binary

I am just curious to know, what does make a machine to know whether its a -1 or 129 ?

`Unsigned uint8 0b10000001 (0x81 in hex) = 129 in decimal`

`Signed uint8 0b10000001 (0x81 in hex) = -1 in decimal`

Answer (score 0):

If code reads it as an unsigned byte, it is 129.  If code reads as a signed byte, it is -1.  It depends on what the *code* is, not just the data.